# Как правильно засунуть все мои асинхронные функции Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как правильно сделать, что бы пока не выполниться блок кода под номером 1, не выполнялось действие номер 2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
export const getAllQues = (collection) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
    db.settings(settings);
    const allquestions = {};
    const docRef = db.collection(collection);
    try {
      const doc = await docRef.get();
      doc.forEach(async (item) => {
        const array = [];
        const ref = db.collection(collection).doc(item.id).collection('questions');
        const total = await ref.get();
        total.forEach(async (interval) => {
          array.push(interval.data());
        });
        allquestions[item.id] = array;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
    const result = allquestions;
    dispatch(allQues(result));
    return result;
  };
};
```

Comment: Вопрос до сих пор актуален?

Answer (score -1):

```
Promise.all(doc.map(item => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const ref = db.collection(collection).doc(item.id).collection('questions');
    const total = await ref.get();
    allquestions[item.id] = total.map(interval => interval.data());
    resolve();
})));
```

Comment: Ну и нафига создавать новый Promise вокруг асинхронной функции?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov ну так а как по другому выполнить мою задачу?

Comment: @sinevitch проще

Comment: Подскажите если не трудно?

Answer (score -2):

Ниже приведен код, который решает вашу задачу. В нем я использовал библиотеку bluebird, которая предоставляет расширенный функционал работы с промисами.
Блок кода под номером 1 был вынесен в отдельную асинхронную функцию, которая будет вызываться с await и позволит вам выполнить блок кода 2, только после выполнения этой функции.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

export const getAllQues = (collection) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
    db.settings(settings);
    const docRef = db.collection(collection);
    const allquestions = await getAllQuestions(docRef, db);
    dispatch(allQues(allquestions));
    return allquestions;
  };
};

async function getAllQuestions(docRef, db) {
    try {
        const doc = await docRef.get();
        const allquestions = {};
        await Promise.each(items, async (item) => {
          const ref = db.collection(collection).doc(item.id).collection('questions');
          const total = await ref.get();
          const intervals = await Promise.map(total, (interval) => interval.data());
          allquestions[item.id] = intervals;
        });

        return allquestions;
      } catch (e) {
        throw e;
       }
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь пожалуйста оставлять более подробные ответы. Что это за фрагмент кода?